# Задан текст, в котором входят только цифры и буквы. Определить, является ли этот текст десятичной записью числа, кратного 4?

Tags: c++

Собственно трудность для меня состоит в том, что бы запихнуть в проверку слово состоящее только из цифр, то есть необходимо создать некий фильтр.
!!!Важно, нельзя использовать читерские функции типо atoi и так далее.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char str[100];
    cin.get(str, 100);
    int b, kolvo=0;
    for (int j = 0; str[j] != '\n'; j++)
    {
        str[j] = b;
        if (b == ' ')
            kolvo++; //Подсчет количества слов
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < kolvo; i++) // ????
    {
        if (str[i]=' ')
        {
            //????
        }
        int ch = 0; // перевод в десятичную из ASCII
        for (int g = 0; g < strlen(str); g++)
        {
            ch = ch * 10 + (int(str[g]) - int('0'));
        }
        if (ch % 4 == 0)
            cout << "Chislo " << ch << " kratno 4" << endl;
        else
            cout << "Chislo " << ch << " ne kratno 4" << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А там и не надо запихивать слово. Признак делимости на 4 требует проверки только двух последних цифр. Следовательно, сначала мы пробегаем циклом по всем символам, смотрим есть ли там нецифровые символы, если их нет то проверяем два последних символа. Если надо через функцию, передавайте туда указатель на массив, длину не надо, у строк признаком конца является нуль-терминатор.

Comment: И `cin.get` читает только один символ, нужно `cin.getline`.